# how to sum values from two tables and date range between

Tags: mysql

I want to sum values from two tables using date range. I tried this,

```
SELECT sum(t1.rcv),sum(t2.amount)
FROM tbl_stock AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl_amount AS t2 ON t1.date=t2.date
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN t1.'2018-12-01' AND t2.'2018-12-12';
```

But this didn't work and gave a syntax error.

Comment: Both here and in response to the answer below you've said there is a syntax error but you haven't shared with us **WHAT** the error is. Help us help you by updating your post with the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @Dave, here is showing me when i apply it #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2018-12-01' AND t2.'2018-12-12'
) - (
  SELECT sum(t2.amount)
  FROM tbl_amo' at line 4

Comment: `'2018-12-12'` is a field name in both tables ?????? * *facepalm* *

Comment: @Akina, yes both tables date column name is same.

Comment: if i do sum values from one table using  date range, it works fine, but i try to two tables of sum using date range, it is not working.

Comment: Your error message does not match your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this..

```
SELECT (
  SELECT sum(rcv)
  FROM tbl_stock
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-12'
) - (
  SELECT sum(amount)
  FROM tbl_amount
  WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-12'
);
```

Comment: not working, showing sql syntax error.

Comment: @Faruk try that, and if it doesn't work tell me the error

Comment: yes it is working but i want to see read data like sum of rcv, sum of amount , sum of both table , for example 100----70---170